# Python os.system() shell has different java version than the travis build environment

Tags: java, python-3.x, shell, travis-ci

In a travis build environment:

```
language: java
dist: xenial
jdk:
  - openjdk13
script:
  - java -version
  - script.py
```

The first java -version outputs JDK13, but when using os.system(java -version) inside the python script JDK8 is shown.

I don't understand why there is a difference, and how to get a JDK13 capable shell from inside the python script as well.

Answer (score 0):

copied from the travis-ci community, thanks again: native-api

This is the handiwork of pyenv. It prepends a few entries to PATH when Python is run through its shim.

Prepending /usr/bin for system version was removed in 1.2.14, the preinstalled version is older.

To workaround that, run Python directly:

/usr/bin/python (or whichever installation you want to use), or
"$(pyenv which python)"